# Can Jmeter help to measure performance of non-web applications?

Tags: jmeter, performance

Can i use Jmeter to measure the performance of a specific action in a non-web based application. If so which sampler should i use?

Answer (score 1):

For non-web based application, have a look at [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/). Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to integrate Sikuli with Jenkins

Comment: Yes, it is ([see here](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/207756)). But personally I have not done it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the answer is **yes**, it depends on what protocol(s) your application is using, JMeter is a multiprotocol tool and it can mimic the following protocols out of the box:

- FTP via [FTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#FTP_Request) sampler
- Databases via [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler
- LDAP via [LDAP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#LDAP_Request) sampler
- Mail via [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) and [Mail Reader Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler)
- MQ via [JMS Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html)
- Custom protocols via [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) or [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler or [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler (you may need to have extra libraries in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath))

See [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) to get the overall idea and some insights.